# Map Iterable Tuple2 to Tuple2

Tags: java, dictionary, rdd

I have a `JavaPairRDD<String, Iterable<Tuple2<String, Double>>>`
I want to get a `JavaPairRDD<Tuple2<Tuple2<String, String>Double>` because I want to reduce it by key afterwards.

```
JavaPairRDD<Tuple2<String, String>,Double> reduceBK = x.reduceByKey(new Function2<Double,Double,Double>() {
            public Double call(Double a,Double b) { return a+b;}
            });
```

How can I transform the Tuple2 with the list inside?